# How to change size occupied by an array formula?

Tags: excel, vsto

I have a formula, that returns array. Is it possible to change range occupied for result of this formula? (programmatically)

Answer (score 0):

no, it's not possible. you have to delete the array and make a new one.

from the [microsoft support website](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Rules-for-changing-array-formulas-8A80C2C1-44C1-42C3-88C1-37A3A7C2D367):
*you can't delete cells in an array formula (you'll see a "You cannot change part of an array" error), but you can delete the entire formula and start over.*

so in order to achieve this, you first have to select all the cells in the array, press `delete` and then type / paste the formula again in a new range.

Comment: See the question: programmatically.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [this site from Microsoft](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/introducing-array-formulas-in-excel-HA001087290.aspx).

Scroll down to the section called "Rules for entering and changing array formulas"